# SQL error or missing database (no such column: Lale30)

Tags: java, sqlite, jdbc

у меня есть код

```
public Database() throws ClassNotFoundException, SQLException, IOException
    {
        Class.forName("org.sqlite.JDBC");
        conn = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:sqlite:" + createDatabaseFile());
        DoxxedBans.api.getLogger().log(Level.INFO, "Database connected");

        statement = conn.createStatement();
        statement.execute("CREATE TABLE if not exists 'bans' ('id' INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT, 'player' text, 'playerUUID' text, 'reason' text, 'playerIP' text, 'executor' text, 'executorUUID' text, 'bandate' INT, 'banend' INT);");
    }
```

и есть код

```
public static List<BanPlayer> getPlayer(String player)
    {
        try {
            List<BanPlayer> bans = new LinkedList<>();

            ResultSet rs = statement.executeQuery(
                "SELECT * FROM 'bans' WHERE 'player' = " + player
            );
            while (rs.next())
            {
                bans.add(new BanPlayer(
                    rs.getInt("id"),
                    rs.getString("player"),
                    rs.getString("playerUUID"),
                    rs.getString("reason"),
                    rs.getString("playerIP"),
                    rs.getString("executor"),
                    rs.getString("executorUUID"),
                    rs.getInt("bandate"),
                    rs.getInt("banend")
                ));
            }

            return bans;
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            e.printStackTrace();
            return new LinkedList<>();
        }
    }
```

так вот, я пытаюсь получить все записи из таблицы 'bans' где player равен указанному параментру
но у меня ошибка

```
[14:49:50 WARN]: org.sqlite.SQLiteException: [SQLITE_ERROR] SQL error or missing database (no such column: Lale30)
[14:49:50 WARN]:        at org.sqlite.core.DB.newSQLException(DB.java:909)
[14:49:50 WARN]:        at org.sqlite.core.DB.newSQLException(DB.java:921)
[14:49:50 WARN]:        at org.sqlite.core.DB.throwex(DB.java:886)
[14:49:50 WARN]:        at org.sqlite.core.NativeDB.prepare_utf8(Native Method)
[14:49:50 WARN]:        at org.sqlite.core.NativeDB.prepare(NativeDB.java:127)
[14:49:50 WARN]:        at org.sqlite.core.DB.prepare(DB.java:227)
[14:49:50 WARN]:        at org.sqlite.jdbc3.JDBC3Statement.executeQuery(JDBC3Statement.java:81)
[14:49:50 WARN]:        at me.doxxed.api.database.Database.getPlayer(Database.java:46)
[14:49:50 WARN]:        at me.doxxed.DoxxedBans.join(DoxxedBans.java:47)
[14:49:50 WARN]:        at com.destroystokyo.paper.event.executor.asm.generated.GeneratedEventExecutor4.execute(Unknown Source)
[14:49:50 WARN]:        at org.bukkit.plugin.EventExecutor$2.execute(EventExecutor.java:70)
[14:49:50 WARN]:        at co.aikar.timings.TimedEventExecutor.execute(TimedEventExecutor.java:78)
[14:49:50 WARN]:        at org.bukkit.plugin.RegisteredListener.callEvent(RegisteredListener.java:62)
[14:49:50 WARN]:        at org.bukkit.plugin.SimplePluginManager.callEvent(SimplePluginManager.java:513)
[14:49:50 WARN]:        at net.minecraft.server.v1_12_R1.PlayerList.onPlayerJoin(PlayerList.java:370)
[14:49:50 WARN]:        at net.minecraft.server.v1_12_R1.PlayerList.a(PlayerList.java:183)
[14:49:50 WARN]:        at net.minecraft.server.v1_12_R1.LoginListener.b(LoginListener.java:178)
[14:49:50 WARN]:        at net.minecraft.server.v1_12_R1.LoginListener.e(LoginListener.java:68)
[14:49:50 WARN]:        at net.minecraft.server.v1_12_R1.NetworkManager.a(NetworkManager.java:273)
[14:49:50 WARN]:        at net.minecraft.server.v1_12_R1.ServerConnection.c(ServerConnection.java:150)
[14:49:50 WARN]:        at net.minecraft.server.v1_12_R1.MinecraftServer.D(MinecraftServer.java:948)
[14:49:50 WARN]:        at net.minecraft.server.v1_12_R1.DedicatedServer.D(DedicatedServer.java:423)
[14:49:50 WARN]:        at net.minecraft.server.v1_12_R1.MinecraftServer.C(MinecraftServer.java:774)
[14:49:50 WARN]:        at net.minecraft.server.v1_12_R1.MinecraftServer.run(MinecraftServer.java:666)
[14:49:50 WARN]:        at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:833)
```

файл базы данных -> https://cdn.discordapp.com/attachments/1017643263911526433/1036170772479217704/database.db
он не большой, можно просмотреть через https://inloop.github.io/sqlite-viewer/
или же вот скриншот[image: да]

Comment: `"SELECT * FROM bans WHERE player = '" + player + "'";`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Попробуй сделать так

```
PreparedStatement ps = conn.prepareStatement(
                "SELECT * FROM bans WHERE player = ?" 
            );
ps.setString(1, player);
ResultSet rs = ps.executeQuery();
```